# Using pig, How do I parse and comapre a grouped item

Tags: apache-pig

I have

```
A  B
a, d
a, e
a, y
z, v
z, k
z, o
```

and so on.
Column B is of type cararray and contains key value pairs separated by &.

For example  - d = 'abc=1&c=1&p=success'

What I want to figure out --

Suppose -

d = 'abc=1&c=1&xyz=23423423'

e = 'xyz=1&it=ssd'

y = 'abc=1&c=1&p=success'

For every 'a' I want to figure out if it has column b which contains the same value of abc and have c=1 and p = success. I also want to extract the value of abc and c from d and y.

For instance lets take the above example -

d contains abc=1  and c=1

y contains abc=1 and p= success

So this satisfies what I am looking for i.e for a given 'a' i have same value of abc and c=1 and p =success.

I started with grouping my data :

```
grouped = group data BY (A, B);
```

which gives me

```
a, (a,b)(a,e)(a,y)
z, (z,v)(z,k)(z,o)
```

But after this I am clueless on how to compare data within each group so that the above condition is satisfied.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Please let me know if you want me to clarify further on my question.

Comment: you should start by extracting the data in column B it to a map.  Probably best to do it with a UDF but you could maybe do it with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only concerned with some of the fields in the query string (I assume that's what it is), you will want to split the data with a FOREACH and STRSPLIT. Flatten it so you have something that looks like this
(a, b) where b would be a single key/value from the query ex: abc=1
Filter out the key/value pairs you don't care about, join them back together and then group by the combined key/value pairs. That will give you a list of every a with the same b where b only contains abc=X, c=1 and p=success